# Trying to learn how to compose permutations

Tags: permutations

I am trying to prove myself that $(1)(2)(3)(4) = (12)(12)(3)(4).$

So,

$\begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   2 & 1  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$        $\begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   2 & 1  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$  $\begin{pmatrix}         
   3 & 4 \\              
   3 & 4  \\             
   \end{pmatrix} = (12)(12)(3)(4).$

Let $p = \begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   2 & 1  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$. Then $p \circ p = p^2 = \begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   2 & 1  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   2 & 1  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}.$ So, right to left: $(p \circ p)(1) = p(p(1)) = p(2) = 1$ and $(p \circ p)(2) = p(p(2)) = p(1) = 2.$ Thus, $p \circ p = \begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   1 & 2  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}.$

Let $q = \begin{pmatrix}         
   3 & 4 \\              
   3 & 4  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}.$ Then $(p \circ p) \circ q = p^2 \circ q = \begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   1 & 2  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}         
   3 & 4 \\              
   3 & 4  \\             
   \end{pmatrix} = (1)(2)(3)(4).$

Does that make sense to you? In particular, I am having a problem with  $p^2 \circ q(1) =  p^2(q(1))$ and $p^2 \circ q(3) =  p^2(q(3))$ which are undefined? Generally, how do we compose $\begin{pmatrix}         
   1 & 2 \\              
   1 & 2  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}         
   3 & 4 \\              
   3 & 4  \\             
   \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: I do it in my head.  For example, consider what $(12)(12)(3)(4)$ does to 1.  First 1 goes to 2, then 2 goes to 1.  So 1 goes to 1.  But if you want to write it your war, then it should be $p = \pmatrix{1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4}$ and $q=\pmatrix{1&2&3&4\\1&2&3&4}$.  Note that all one-cycles are the identity.

Comment: @  Stephen Montgomery-Smith, $p(p(1)) = 1, p(p(2)) = 2, p(p(3)) = 3, p(p(4)) = 4$, so $p^2$ is identity. This works out great. Is $(12)(12)(3)(4)$ actually $[(12)(3)(4)][(12)(3)(4)][(1)(2)(3)(4)]$?

Comment: It is.  But it is much easier to write $(12)(3)(4)$ as $(12)$.